# Controlling a brushless DC motor with an Arduino--*without ESC*

Tags: arduino, atmega, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I want to build an ESC using an ATmega328 (used in Arduino Uno).  This is the [Brushless DC Motor](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__42861__Turnigy_Aerodrive_DST_700_Brushless_Outrunner_motor_700kv.html) I've chosen and this is the [MOSFET](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10001&catalogId=10001&productId=812236&) I've chosen to gate the power supply.  It will be used to drive a variable speed propeller in one direction.

I understand the concept of "rotating" the power but I can't seem to complete the puzzle.

1. At what frequency do I have to gate the MOSFET for maximum speed?  The motor is a 700kv at maximum 14.4 volts.  <s>Does that mean I have to gate the MOSFET at 10.08MHz (700KHz * 14.4)?</s>
2. Do I have *have* to sense the rotor position? (Using Hall Effect or sensor)  If so, why?
3. Is a square wave (PWM) or sinusoidal wave better for this application?

---

Edit:

1. I mistook 1kV for 1000rpm-per-volt instead of the correct 1rpm-per-volt.  I also was thinking revolutions-per-**second** instead of the correct revolutions-per-**minute**.  It is much more plausable now.

Comment: "the MOSFET" ... you do understand you'll need six MOSFETs, right?

Comment: Do a search for AVR444 - Sensorless control of 3-phase brushless DC ... It's not trivial.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, Why 6? Can't I run it with 3?

Comment: If it's Y-wound you may be able to run it with 3, but 6 (3 half bridges) is the normal way.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the ATmega328's smaller sibling the ATmega8 is among the top choices for implementing hobby speed controls (most are either that or an SiLabs 8051).  Open source firmware projects for those may port right over, or at least give you some practical ideas on working approaches.

Comment: you can take a look at Benjamin Vedder's work on his [homepage](http://vedder.se) and his YT channel. It's amazing and you can see how complex it is and to get an outline of what you try to do. Maybe it would be a good idea to start off with brushed DC motors, as they don't need a modulation of the three phases as the brushless siblings do.

Comment: @c-a Benjamin's work is amazing!  I put this project on hold because I wanted to utilize BEMF instead of a sensors.  Looks like his design has everything I wanted and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atmel have a few application notes about brushless motor control without sensors, e.g. http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8192.pdf or http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8306.pdf

2/ You need to sense the rotor position somehow. The magnetic field in the motor coils needs to rotate slightly in advance of the magnetic field in the rotor in order to pull it around, so you need to know where the rotor is to switch the next set of coils on at the right time. If the motor does not have hall effect sensors then you do this by sensing the emf in the coils. This only works once the motor is rotating, so there is a slower fixed sequence to start the motor.

1/ The kv number is the rpm per volt at no load, so at 14.4V the motor might be expected to be going at 10,000 rpm which is 167Hz. 10MHz would be very fast for a motor - the tips of a 10cm propeller would be at 2% of the speed of light.

3/ As the app notes will tell you, the wave form of the field required for these motors is 'trapezoidal' which is essentially a square wave.

Comment: I know propellers lose efficiency when the tips go supersonic... what happens when they become relativistic? :)

Comment: That leads to another question. If it's 167Hz and I run it the PWM at +20KHz how do I variable the speed of the motor?

Comment: The PWM only needs to be higher than the transistory's switch-on period - in this case, with 3 coils you have 6 switch-on periods per rotation so your 20kHz PWM would be 20 PWM cycles over the time each transistor is switched on for ( 20kHz / ( 167*6 switch-ons per second ).

Comment: +1 for the bonus near-relativistic tangential rotor velocity note + calculation. :)

Comment: Oops, just noticed: at (2), OP's very interesting question about having to sense the motor position: "If so, why?" is not answered. (I wanted to take my (anyway cheezy...) upvote right back for that, but (fortunately) don't have the reps.)

Comment: @Sz. it's covered in the linked note, but I've added a very simple explanation

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Still wondering though (not sure if OP had the same in mind), exactly because "...there is a slower fixed sequence to start the motor": you could try an accelerating open-loop ramp-up sequence, and the rotor would keep turning, perhaps quite fast eventually and perhaps even producing some torque. This "stepper mode" would kinda' work (after some tuning), but would be very inefficient and hostile to the motor (and perhaps the driver), and speed control would be horrible, too. So, open-loop BLDC driving _is_ possible, just way inferior. Is this correct? Thx.

Comment: @Sz yes, you start open loop but you can't get both speed and torque - if you put full current through it with slow commutation, you'll get the same torque, but without feedback it will be horribly jerky, or you can commutate it at the required speed and you might not get any torque at all.

Comment: And, as I also realized, even more problematic is that an open-loop drive would need to assume a certain fixed load. Any change in that (which is inevitable in any meaningful application), and it's all going to become hopelessly wonky. So, a message to OP (@NathanGoings): I consider _this_ as the ultimate reason for "yes, you *have to* use feedback & closed loop".